# Spring 4 @controller config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm migrating a webapp from spring 2.5 to spring 4, but I found a problem.
I have two differents url that work for two different configurations of the same class.
In my old version, I have something like:

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/url1.htm">bean1</prop>
                <prop key="/url2.htm">bean2</prop>
              </props>
          </property>
  </bean>
```

and the beans are something like

```
<bean id="bean1" class="com.package.Controller" scope="session">
    <property name="property" value="value of property"/>
</bean>
<bean id="bean2" class="com.package.Controller" scope="session">
    <property name="property" value="a different value of the same property"/>
</bean>
```

How could I do this with the annotations?

Comment: And why would you have to abandon that? The fact that you use Spring 4 doesn't mean the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` should be abandoned. If you have a valid use case then please keep using `Controller`s instead of `@Controller`.

Comment: But it is still available also in Spring 4?? How do I configure it in my annotated @Configuration class?

Comment: Just create an instance and fill the mappings.

Comment: Also migrating doesn't mean you have to drop xml... Don't do everything at once. First upgrade, make it work. Then see if you can move some things to java based config. Don't do the whole thing at once.

Answer (score 1):

Use @Controller annotation on your controller class and map /url1.htm and /url2.htm with @RequestMapping annotation. Look [Spring Reference @RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping).

You will get something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/url1.htm")
public class bean1{

}
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/url2.htm")
public class bean2{

}
```

And set bean properties in each class.
If you dont want to duplicate methods you can do like this

```
@Controller
public class bean1{

   @RequestMapping("/url{id}.htm")
   public void setBeanProp(@PathVariable int id){
     if (id.equals(1))
     ...
     else
     ...


    }
```

Comment: Yes. I know that. I'd like not to duplicate all the methods in each bean because, for me, it's a waste of time and complicate only the future maintenance

Comment: "Duplicate all the methods"? What do you mean, which methods are you duplicating? If there are methods in the controller classes that you want to put in both, you could put them in a class and make both controllers extend that class.